# How can I return the Query result from a Transaction in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am using Hyperledger Composer and the Rest Api but I was wondering if when requesting a new transaction, I can return my query result instead of the newly created transaction that doesn't have any useful information in for me in it.

I could just use the query route from the API but I want to use a Transaction to safely provide data coming from my Assets to the query.

For example if I need to provide a the actual DateTime to the query, I prefer to do it from a transaction coming from Composer than a Date provided from another server that could be wrong or faked.

Comment: Give us a sample of what you are doing

Comment: your question doesn't really explain what you want. You could call an existing query, or build one - using the transaction inputs, including a datetime etc - and you can return the results to (say) an application that called the REST API (transaction) function/endpoint.

Comment: Furthermore, if you're talking about returning results from a transaction (obviously, the transaction itself, and its read/write set if your doing adds/updates etc won't be COMMITTED at the point - be aware) - then see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#returning-data-from-transaction-functions - if its just a query transaction (to get results) result, scroll down the page to 'Read-only transaction processor functions (query processor functions)' - which represents a non-committing, query based transaction (less cost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but if you want to use pre-defined query in your transaction, refer https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries.

And you can return data from transaction. Read following
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts